# how to get Sum of a column avoiding gaps in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:
Table 1 has ID, Quantity, FK_FirstItem, FK_LastItem, FK_ShippentID,  etc.
Table 2 has ItemID, SerialNumber, Barcode etc...

Lets says Table 2 is as follows:

| ItemID | Serialnum | Barcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | B10.. |
| 2 | 102 | B10.. |
| 3 | 103 | B10.. |
| 4 | 104 | B10.. |
| 5 | 105 | B10.. |
| 6 | 106 | B10.. |
| 7 | 107 | B10.. |
| 8 | 108 | B10.. |
| 9 | 109 | B10.. |
| 10 | 110 | B10.. |
| 11 | 111 | B10.. |
| 12 | 112 | B10.. |
| 13 | 113 | B10.. |
| 14 | 114 | B10.. |
| 15 | 115 | B10.. |
| 16 | 116 | B10.. |
| 17 | 117 | B10.. |
| 18 | 118 | B10.. |
| 19 | 119 | B10.. |
| 20 | 120 | B10.. |
| 21 | 121 | B10.. |
| 22 | 122 | B10.. |
| 23 | 123 | B10.. |
| 24 | 124 | B10.. |
| 25 | 125 | B10.. |
| 26 | 126 | B10.. |
| 27 | 127 | B10.. |
| 28 | 128 | B10.. |
| 29 | 129 | B10.. |
| 30 | 130 | B10.. |

and Table 1 :

| ID | Quantity | FK_FirstItem | FK_LastItem | FK_ShippentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 26 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | Null |
| 3 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 26 |
| 4 | 3 | 10 | 12 | 26 |
| 5 | 3 | 13 | 15 | Null |
| 6 | 3 | 16 | 18 | Null |
| 7 | 3 | 19 | 21 | Null |
| 8 | 3 | 22 | 24 | 26 |
| 9 | 3 | 25 | 27 | Null |
| 10 | 3 | 28 | 30 | Null |

I need to get the total number of cards (SUM (Quantity )), and count of boxes (Count (*)) (table 2 is boxes, each row 1 box), and beginning first item serial number, last item serial number where shippent is null.
But exclude the gaps. There are gap in serial numbers when some boxes are shipped. Items serial number is sequential.
This query will be called multiple times as a dynamic query.

I am trying window functions, with Lag I can get previous serial number, but I don't know how to group by or partition escaping gaps.

With query:

```
Select 
  Sum(a.Quantity) over() as TotalQnty, 
  b.Serialnum as FrstItemSer, c.Serialnum as LastItemSer,
  Count(ID) over() as BoxQuantity
from table1 a
join table2 b ON a.FK_FirstItem  = b.ItemID
join table2 c ON a.FK_LastItem  = c.ItemID 
where FK_ShippentID is null
```

I am getting the total result:

| # | TotalQty | FrstItemSer | LastItemSer | BoxQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 104 | 130 | 6 |

in this result total 18 items in 6 boxes were not shipped. And items serial numbers are from 104 to 130. But items w/serial# 101 - 104, 107 - 112, and 122 - 124 are shipped.

The result I want to get is:

| # | TotalQty | FrstItemSer | LastItemSer | BoxQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 104 | 106 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 113 | 121 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | 125 | 130 | 2 |

where it says total 3 items from 104 to 106 shipped in 1 box, then
total 9 items from 113 to 121 shipped in 3 boxes, then
total 6 items from 125 to 130 shipped in 2 boxes

Comment: More information is needed. Your desired results appears to indicate that the boxes contain 3 items each, but there is nothing in your source data that would indicate that. Also, you ask about handling gaps, but your sample data seems to contain no gaps. I suggest that you post a complete ***minimal reproducible example*** containing schema, sample data covering special cases, the query you have tried so far, plus actual vs desired results. Ideally, code this all up in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-) and post the resulting link back here to give us a stating point.

Comment: there needs to be a traceable relationship from sample data to expected result - without this we have to guess at what you intend. Other than that the format of data + query + expected is good. However "table1" looks like the result of a query, if that is true can we see that query too.

Comment: Just one join: `Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t2.ItemID between t1.FK_FirstItem and t2.FK_LastItem`. Use a regular `group by t1.ItemID` with regular aggregates (i.e., without `over ()`).

Comment: sorry made a mistake from and join tables, corrected it

Comment: The join condition is a range. I believe I've given sufficient information to solve this. I'm not sure if my table references were backward or if something got changed.